# MySQL: Delete rows from either of two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables setup like this:

`user_users`

```
ID    ColA    ColB
55    This    That
56    Other   Stuff
```

`user_meta`

```
ID    UserID    MetaName    MetaValue
1     56        some_name   some_value
2     56        other_name  other_vaue
3     99        this_too    equals_this
```

So, there can be multiple rows in the `user_meta` table attributed to a given `UserID`. When I remove a user, I need to also remove any rows in the `user_meta` table attributed to that user.

Here's what I have:

`DELETE user_users, user_meta FROM user_users LEFT JOIN user_meta ON user_meta.UserID = user_users.ID WHERE user_users.ID = 56`

This will work great in these scenarios:

1. If the user exists in `user_users` but no rows exist for this user in `user_meta`
2. If the user exists in `user_users` and rows exist for this user in `user_meta`

The problem is that if (for some reason) the user ID exists in `user_meta` but NOT in `user_users`, the rows are not removed from the `user_meta` table.

For all practical reasons, this query *should* work in all cases (because how would you have user meta saved for a nonexistent user?), but just in case, I'd like to ensure that the query would also remove any rows in the `user_meta` table with the `UserID` EVEN IF that user does not exist in the `user_users` table.

So, I'd like this query to remove any rows in the `user_meta` table with `UserID = 99`, but it doesn't, because no `ID` of 99 exists in the `user_users` table:

```
DELETE user_users, user_meta FROM user_users LEFT JOIN user_meta ON user_meta.UserID = user_users.ID WHERE user_users.ID = 99
```

How do I update this query to delete from either/both tables regardless if the ID exists on either of the other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is a good candidate for using cascading deletion constraints.  You want child records in the `user_meta` table to be deleted whenever a parent record in `user_users` is deleted.  Assuming there is already a foreign key constraint on `UserID` in the `user_meta` table, you could try:

```
ALTER TABLE user_meta DROP FOREIGN KEY user_id_key;

ALTER TABLE user_meta
ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_key
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES user_users (ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This assumes that you already have a foreign key constraint on `user_meta#UserID`.  If you don't, then ignore the first `ALTER TABLE` statement.

With this constraint in place, deleting a user record from `user_users` would automatically cause all child records in `user_meta` to be deleted.

Comment: Wow... that's new to me. Looks great, but I had some errors:
On the first `ALTER TABLE` I had: `Can't DROP 'user_id_key'; check that column/key exists`, so I tried the second, and got:
`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: This is probably coming from that `user_meta` has one or more records which point to a `UserID` which does not exist anymore in `user_users`.  Check your data for this.

Comment: Wow that's great! This is a new concept for me so I can't wait to learn more about it. Thank you so much!